# Only Time part of the date is to be inserted in Oracle 9i Database table

Tags: sql, oracle, time

We have a small requirement in our project.

We are using informatica for running our scheduled jobs. Requirement Is such that we need to keep a track of the jobs that if a job fails and does not get scheduled again AT ITS SCHEDULED TIME it should send a notification to the team.

The table structure is as such:

```
CREATE TABLE PROD.BDW_SCHEDULED_JOBS
(
  Folder   VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)             NOT NULL,
  Workflow  VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)             NOT NULL,
  Schedule_day  VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  Schedule_Time  varchar2 (50 byte)
)
```

I want only the scheduled time to be available for a particular workflow.
I tried changing the datatype for TIME column but whenever I insert it would bring date along :(

Please help. Searched online but all the answers were discouraging.

Thanks in Advance

Bhargavi

Answer (score 0):

you can extract `Time` from the `SYSDATE` using `TO_CHAR()` by specifying time parameters, like:

```
INSERT INTO PROD.BDW_SCHEDULED_JOBS VALUES('Folder...', 'Workflow...', 'Schedule_day...',
   TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH12:MI:SS AM'));
```